# How to get te running time of the diameter of a graph?

Tags: performance, algorithm, graph, big-o

If you have a simple undirected graph G(V, E), how can you find the diameter of the graph in O((|V|+|E|) * lg |V|) running time?

Comment: unweighted, and undirected.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best known algorithm for unweighted undirected graphs takes Õ(n^ω), where n = |V| and ω < 2.376 is the exponent of fast matrix multiplication.  And O((|V|+|E|) * lg |V|) would give us Õ(n^2), which is better than the best known algorithm.  Look at the introduction section of http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6181 for a brief survey and references.